# Как составить условие для прелоадер по времени?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как правильно составить условия для прелоадера:
Если страница полностью не загружена в течении 10 секунд, то не показывай прелоадер?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    fadePreLoader(preLoader);
}, 10000);


window.onload = function () {
    fadePreLoader(preLoader);
};
```

**Как эти два кода совместить, что бы не выполнялась функция `fadePreLoader(preLoader);` по два раза?**

```js
var preLoader = document.getElementById("before-load");

function fadePreLoader(el) {
    el.style.opacity = 1;
    var interPreLoader = setInterval(function () {
        el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;
        if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05) {
            clearInterval(interPreLoader);
            preLoader.style.display = "none";
        }
    }, 16);
}


setTimeout(function () {
    fadePreLoader(preLoader);
}, 10000);


window.onload = function () {
    fadePreLoader(preLoader);
};
```

```css
#before-load {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ec1c24;
  z-index: 1501;
  border: 5px solid #ec1c24;
  color:#fff;
}

.before-load__logo,
.before-load__preloader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.before-load__logo {
  width: 200px;
  top: 75px;
}

.before-load__preloader {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="before-load">
  Внимание, работает прелоадер.
</div>

Тело сайта
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что через `setTimeout` не работает?

Comment: Да, простите работает, не уточнил момент, как эти два кода совместить, что бы не выполнялась функция fadePreLoader(preLoader); по два раза?

Comment: Сайт может не загружаться очень долго из-за внешнего скрипта, соответственно прелоадер будет крутиться, пока пользователь не закроет сайт.
Задача же заключается в следующем:
Если сайт в течении 10 секунд не загрузится, скрыть прелоадер!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб не выполнялась два раза удалить setTimeout и onload

```
var timerId = setTimeout( transfer, 10000 );
window.addEventListener( 'load', transfer );

function transfer () {
    clearTimeout( timerId );
    window.removeEventListener( 'load', transfer );
    fadePreLoader( preLoader );
}
```

А вот как определить начало загрузки документа, пока на нем нет ни одного скрипта, скорее всего не получится.

**Можно** "схитрить"

Сделать независимо от скрипта анимацию и потом ее удалить,
тогда не важно когда загрузится скрипт

```css
@keyframes __load__ {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
#before-load {
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: __load__;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s; /* 10 */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>before-load</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="before-load">
            Внимание, работает прелоадер (2s).
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, через замыкание. Можно вынести `wasHidden` в глобальную область видимости, но это еще больший костыль получится.

```js
var preLoader = document.getElementById("before-load");

var fadePreLoader = (function() {
  var wasHidden = false;
  return function(el) {
    if (el.style.opacity != 1 && wasHidden === false) {
      wasHidden = true;
      el.style.opacity = 1;
      var interPreLoader = setInterval(function() {
        el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;
        if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05) {
          clearInterval(interPreLoader);
          preLoader.style.display = "none";
        }
      }, 16);
    }
  }
})();


setTimeout(function() {
  fadePreLoader(preLoader);
}, 3000);


window.onload = function() {
  fadePreLoader(preLoader);
};
```

```css
#before-load {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ec1c24;
  z-index: 1501;
  border: 5px solid #ec1c24;
  color: #fff;
}

.before-load__logo,
.before-load__preloader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.before-load__logo {
  width: 200px;
  top: 75px;
}

.before-load__preloader {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="before-load">
  Внимание, работает прелоадер.
</div>

Тело сайта
```